# phia testInteraction and mixed model output p-values differences

Tags: mixed-model, p-value, interaction, contrasts

In an experiment I a priory hypothesized that the effect of treatment (Control/Sand) may be mediated by Sex (Male/Female) and subjects weight. Because of sex dimorphism I scaled weight for each sex separately, leading to the following model

```
library(lme4)
NoCoop1 <- glmer(cbind(WL5$ActiveNoWNoG,WL5$ActiveNoWNoG_Fail) ~ Treatment*Sex*Weight_D2_SexScale+TreatmentWeek+(1|AnimalID)+(1|Nrow), family="binomial", data=WL5)
```

After model simplification the minimal model (NoCoop4) output,

```
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace
Approximation) [glmerMod]
Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: cbind(WL5$ActiveNoWNoG, WL5$ActiveNoWNoG_Fail) ~ Treatment +  
Sex + Weight_D2_SexScale + (1 | AnimalID) + (1 | Nrow) +  
Treatment:Sex + Treatment:Weight_D2_SexScale
Data: WL5

 AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
645.1    664.9   -314.6    629.1       80 

Scaled residuals: 
 Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.36062 -0.48251  0.00465  0.44668  1.42279 

Random effects:
Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
Nrow     (Intercept) 0.01768  0.1329  
AnimalID (Intercept) 0.05713  0.2390  
Number of obs: 88, groups:  Nrow, 88; AnimalID, 44

Fixed effects:
                                 Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                      -1.28541    0.07196 -17.864   <2e-16 ***
TreatmentSand                    -0.09929    0.07064  -1.406   0.1599    
SexMale                          -0.17346    0.10300  -1.684   0.0922 .  
Weight_D2_SexScale                0.06952    0.06339   1.097   0.2728    
TreatmentSand:SexMale             0.22353    0.10132   2.206   0.0274 *  
TreatmentSand:Weight_D2_SexScale -0.15342    0.06371  -2.408   0.0160 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

suggests that females and males respond differently to treatment with females decreasing and males increasing the expression of the response variable. The first contrast of the model output suggests that the effect of treatment on female is non-significant, but what is the effect of treatment on males? I answered this question using the testInteraction function from phia package as followed

```
library(phia)
TreatmentEffect_Sex<-testInteractions(NoCoop4,pairwise="Treatment",fixed="Sex", adjustment="none")
```

which returns

```
Chisq Test: 
P-value adjustment method: none
                        Value Df  Chisq Pr(>Chisq)  
Control-Sand : Female 0.53362  1 3.5215    0.06058 .
Control-Sand :   Male 0.47780  1 1.6401    0.20031  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

I do not understand why the contrasts p value returned for females and males by phia are different than the p values returned by the contrast in my minimal model output (to get treatment effect on male I simply set males as the new reference in the model)? I assumed they should be exactly the same.

Curiously if in my full model weights are scaled for males and females together as followed

```
    library(lme4)
NoCoop1<-glmer(cbind(WL5$ActiveNoWNoG,WL5$ActiveNoWNoG_Fail)~Treatment*Sex*scale(Weight_D2)+TreatmentWeek+(1|AnimalID)+(1|Nrow),family="binomial",data=WL5)
```

The p values returned by phia and the model output are exactly the same as I would have anticipated.